# What's wrong with my label formatting?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, labeling, annotation, maplex

I have some formatting issues with my labels.  I am using a fairly straight forward expression (see below).  It sort of works fine but **some formatting is being ignored, namely the ALL CAPS ACP tags**. All owner names are lower case with first letter capitalized.  I want to display them as all caps and only SOME labels come out with owners capitalized. I am also using italics  tags when a claim number value exists and that works fine.

Another issue is that although I am  **NOT spreading characters** in Maplex, **some labels but not all have Owner's names spread**, but strangely not the PIN numbers and claims numbers all of which are a part of one single string variable.

There are other issues with Stacking Labels in Maplex which doesn't seem to stack properly when using Stacking Separator but let's ignore that for this question.

Is there a way to fix this or do i need to export to annotations and fix manually?

```
Function FindLabel ([Owner], [MNDMF_Active_Mining_Claims_CLAIM_NUM], [PIN], [PIN_Surface], [PIN_Mining] )
FindLabel = ""

if not isnull([Owner]) then
if trim([Owner]) <> "" then
FindLabel = FindLabel & trim("<ACP>" & [Owner] & "</ACP>")
end if
end if

if not isnull([MNDMF_Active_Mining_Claims_CLAIM_NUM]) then
if trim([MNDMF_Active_Mining_Claims_CLAIM_NUM]) <> "" then
if len(FindLabel) > 0 then
FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline
end if
FindLabel = "<ITA>" & "Claim: " & [MNDMF_Active_Mining_Claims_CLAIM_NUM] & "</ITA>" 
end if
end if  

if not isnull([PIN]) then
if trim([PIN]) <> "" then
if len(FindLabel) > 0 then
FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline
end if
FindLabel = FindLabel & trim([PIN])
end if
end if

if not isnull([PIN_Surface]) then
if trim([PIN_Surface]) <> "" then
if len(FindLabel) > 0 then
FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline
end if
FindLabel = FindLabel & trim([PIN_Surface])& " S"
end if
end if

if not isnull([PIN_Mining]) then
if trim([PIN_Mining]) <> "" then
if len(FindLabel) > 0 then
FindLabel = FindLabel & vbnewline
end if
FindLabel = FindLabel & trim([PIN_Mining])& " M"
end if
end if

End Function
```

Comment: If you have Maplex enabled, have you tried turning that off and seeing how your FindLabel works then?

Answer (score 2):

Both "<" and "&" are special characters that cause formatting to fail if those are in your text strings. You have to replace these in your code like this:

```
Function FindLabel ([LABELFIELD])
  NewString = Replace([LABELFIELD],"&","&amp;")  
  FindLabel = "<ITA>" & NewString & "</ITA>"
End Function
```

There's more information about formatting in the [help documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-text/using-text-formatting-tags-about-text-formatting-t.htm)